# How to draw a line-shape with a single broken point in MS Powerpoint?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, drawing

Following is the shape that I am trying to achieve in Microsoft Office Powerpoint.
[image: Line-shape with a broken point]

Now, I can draw it using two separate shapes. **Problem** is: whenever I have to adjust the line I need to change both shapes (one straight line and a line with an arrow in one end). This is troublesome when there are more shapes like this.

Is there any way so that line will maintain a break-point and adjustment won't require a lengthy process? Or is there any better tool to draw engineering methodologies such as networking architecture, work-process of a model, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This got me there (on powerpoint 2019):

- Insert > Shape > Choose the line that has an arrow at one end, with *two* kinks in it
- When the shape appears, there should be a nodule in the middle of the line
  Drag it to whichever side you wish

[image]

Edit: there are also bigger "block arrows" farther down the list but they're a bit cartoonish and blocky

Comment: Yeah, I was just about to write this. You saved my time.

Answer (score 1):

Use the polygon tool to draw your shape (one single polygon, rather than two different shapes). You can then give one end of the polygon an arrowhead, just as with lines.